# Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for NavbarSandbox: (?, ?)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, web, karma-jasmine

Please help me to resolve this issue.I have tried many things but it not resolved and there are so many things on the net but did't get the solution. My problem is there some classes that I am passing in component constructor and now it is throwing error on krma testing.

my component code

```
`import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { NavbarSandbox } from '../../../navbar/sandbox/navbar.sandbox';
import { ServiceProviderResult } from '../../../shared/models/service-provider';

@Component({
  selector: 'ccw-nav-bar',
  templateUrl: './nav-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-bar.component.scss']
})
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {
  serviceProviderList$: Observable<ServiceProviderResult[]>;
  constructor(public store: Store<any>, public navSandBox: NavbarSandbox) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceProviderList$ = this.navSandBox.getServiceProviderListAPI(null);
  }

  changeCurrentServiceProviderChanged(selectedProviderResult: number): void {
    if (selectedProviderResult !== undefined) {
      this.navSandBox.setSelectedServiceProvider({ id: selectedProviderResult });
    }
  }

  // To get selected dropdown value
  getSelectedData(): void {
    this.navSandBox.getSelectedServiceProvider().subscribe((res) => { console.log(res); });
  }

}
`
```

my spec.ts
    ----------------

```
`import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { NavbarSandbox } from '../../sandbox/navbar.sandbox';
import { MenuBarComponent } from '../../components/menu-bar/menu-bar.component';
import { TitleBarComponent } from '../../components/title-bar/title-bar.component';
import { NavBarComponent } from './nav-bar.component';

describe('NavBarComponent', () => {
  let component: NavBarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavBarComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ NavBarComponent, MenuBarComponent, TitleBarComponent ],
      providers: [NavbarSandbox, Store]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavBarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
`
```

but on karma start --browsers PhantomJS it is showing

NavBarComponent should be created
Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for NavbarSandbox: (?, ?).
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for NavbarSandbox: (?, ?).

### navbarsandbox code:

```
import { AppSandbox } from '../../shared/sandbox/app-sandbox';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store/store';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ProvidersListService } from '../../shared/services/provider-list.service';
import {
    SetServiceProvidersAction,
    SetSelectedServiceProviderId,
    SetDeviceListAction
} from '../../shared/state-management/actions/serviceprovider.actions';
import * as fromRoot from '../../shared/reducers/index';
import { AppStateManager } from '../../shared/state-management/app-state-manager';
import { ServiceAction, ServiceActionTypes } from '../../shared/models/service-action';
import { Device } from '../../shared/models/device';
import { ServiceProviderResult } from '../../shared/models/service-provider';

@Injectable()
export class NavbarSandbox extends AppSandbox {

    constructor(private providersListService: ProvidersListService, private appStateManager: AppStateManager) {
        super();

    }

    // TODO: create action using ActionFactory
    // To get data from service
    public getServiceProviderListAPI(payload: any): Observable<Array<ServiceProviderResult>> {
        const data$ = super.invokeService(new ServiceAction(ServiceActionTypes.GET_SERVICE_PROVIDERS, payload), this.providersListService)
            .subscribe((res: Array<ServiceProviderResult>) => {
                this.setListOfServiceProviders(new SetServiceProvidersAction(res));
            });
        return this.getListOfServiceProviders();
    }

    getDeviceListByIdAPI(): void {
        let selectedId: number;
        this.getSelectedServiceProvider().subscribe((data) => { selectedId = data.id; });
        const data$ = super.invokeService(new ServiceAction(ServiceActionTypes.GET_DEVICE_LIST, selectedId), this.providersListService)
            .subscribe((res: Array<Device>) => {
                this.setDeviceDatabyId(new SetDeviceListAction(res));
            });
    }

    // To save data in store
    private setListOfServiceProviders(action: Action): void {
        this.appStateManager.saveToStore(action);
    }

    // To set the device data based on selected value
    private setDeviceDatabyId(payload: any): void {
        this.appStateManager.saveToStore(new SetDeviceListAction(payload));
    }

    // To set the selected ID from dropdown
    public setSelectedServiceProvider(payload: any): void {
        this.appStateManager.saveToStore(new SetSelectedServiceProviderId(payload));
        // To call and store device data into store.
        this.getDeviceListByIdAPI();
        this.getDeviceListbySelectedId().subscribe((data) => {console.log(data); });

    }

    // To get data from store
    public getListOfServiceProviders(): Observable<Array<ServiceProviderResult>> {
        return this.appStateManager.getFromStore<Array<ServiceProviderResult>>(state => state.providerState.listOfServiceProviders);
    }

    public getSelectedServiceProvider(): Observable<ServiceProviderResult> {
        return this.appStateManager.getFromStore<ServiceProviderResult>(state => state.providerState.selectedServiceProvider);
    }

    public getDeviceListbySelectedId(): Observable<Array<Device>> {
        return this.appStateManager.getFromStore<Array<Device>>(state => state.providerState.listOfDevices);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your NavbarSandbox code to help more.

Comment: navbar code added.

Comment: Angular is trying to resolve dependencies to create `NavbarSandbox` instance but you didn't provide them. I am talking about `ProvidersListService` and `AppStateManager`

Comment: Yes, These ProvidersListService and AppStateManager also have dependency on another classes. These both have parameterized constructor. So how to resolve these dependency. Can you please share any example for the same situation.

Comment: AppStateManager code: `export class AppStateManager {

    constructor(private store: Store<any>) {

    }
    public saveToStore(action: Action): void {
        // TODO
        this.store.dispatch(action);
    }

    public getFromStore<T>(obj: any): Observable<T> {
        return this.store.select(obj);
    }'